# Arduino Micro with HC-05: receiving data in weird encoding

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I'm just starting using HC-05 Bluetooth module and having some troubles.

Firstly, I connected HC-05 bluetooth module to Arduino Micro board in programming mode (with Key pulled up) and was able to communicate with it sending AT commands (changed name, password, etc).

After that I was pulled down Key pin to let HC-05 operate normally. I was able to find and connect to it (with new name and password, as expected), and even transmit data in both directions. However what I'm receiving is not what I'm expecting. I'm sending some character and receiving sequence of bytes:

- When I send `a` char I receive sequence of bytes `120 248`.
- `b` -> `128 0 248`.
- `c` -> `248 0 248`.
- `d` -> `0 128 248`.

Actually, I've tried few mobile apps (Bluetooth Terminal, Bluetooth Terminal HC-05, Serial Bluetooth Terminal) which provides Bluetooth terminal functionality, and they all are producing different bytes sequences. Ones provided above is for `Bluetooth Terminal` app. I'm obviously missing something..

Could someone give me direction?

P.S. My latest version of sketch is following:

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(9, 8);

void setup()  {
  pinMode(9,INPUT);
  pinMode(8,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("welcome");

  mySerial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
  if (mySerial.available()) {
    while (mySerial.available())
    {
      char c = mySerial.read();
      Serial.print((int) c);
      Serial.print(" ");
      delay(5);
    }
    Serial.println("");
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to make sure, did you check the baudrate on HC-05? Which to be 38400.

Comment: You're awesome! I was successfully using 38400 for programming and thought is should be the same for normal use. But it turns out that 38400 is for programing and not rely on what's baud configuration is set. In my case it was 9600. I knew it's something pretty simple. Thank you!
P.S. You could add this as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: glad it was helpful